# C++ ( Without MFC ) checking if an ini read value is empty

Tags: c++, ini

I am having a little trouble getting the my program to check whether or not a .ini file is empty or contains the path to a webpage.

My .ini file:

```
[WEB]
Location =
```

The following is my code. It will not enter the if statement and show the Dialogbox:

```
GetPrivateProfileStringA("WEBSERVICES", "Location", "none set", webLocation, sizeof(webLocation), pathStr);

    if (webLocation == "1"){
        DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
        EnableMenuItem(hmenu, ID_WEBSERVICES_RUN, MF_GRAYED);
        }
```

Any help on this issue would be appreciated.

Regards
           -Dan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` condition is incorrect, use [`strcmp()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/) to compare `char` arrays:

```
if (0 == strcmp(webLocation, "1")){
```

This:

```
if (webLocation == "1"){
```

compares the address of `webLocation` to the address of the string literal `"1"`, which always will be `false` (in this case).

*Note that the section name `WEB` does not match that specified in the call to `GetPrivateProfileStringA()`.*

Comment: Ah that explains it. This is now working perfectly. Thank you for your quick, informative response.